# Showing "there is an error in xml document(0,0)" while XMlFile is reading

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

while reading XML file which is converted to String.

my Code is as follows

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string xmlVal=string.Empty;

using (var reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, ListParam.ToArray()))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadOuterXml());
        xmlVal = sb.ToString(); // You can get the xml as string here.
    }
}

MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();                   

document.LoadXml(xmlVal);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;                       
document.WriteContentTo(writer);
writer.Flush();
mStream.Flush();                     
mStream.Position = 0;                      
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream);
```

by entering to this code it showing the error `there is an error in xml document(0,0)`, but the string have the XMLCollection (`xmlVal`)

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<CollectionlDetail>));
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(mStream))
{
    CollectionlDetailCol= xs.Deserialize(rd) as ObservableCollection<CollectionlDetail>;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] - you need to show what `xmlVal` actually is. It's fairly evident it's not valid XML.

Comment: You may have a space(s) in front of the xml.  xml expect the string to start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: this line is not coming for me during the storeProdure returns the XML.

Comment: I used "FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('Name');" at end of the procedure

Comment: Your loop for reading the XML string is wrong for a start, you overwrite the `xmlVal` each time.

Comment: @charles no, one time only it works at the first time itself